# App Rejected due to Mail

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval, mfmailcomposer

My App got rejected and reason is below:-

```
Did not integrate with iOS features. For example, the email button should enable users to compose emails in the app rather than launching the Mail app.
```

I did not get that what they want. I have used `MFMailComposer` class so what's wrong with it?Any Suggestion.

Comment: Are you displaying a `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Comment: it says u r launching mail app from your app.. but you have to show a mail composer, so that user can compose a mail & send.. show us ur mail composer code..

Comment: Yes i am using `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)pushMail:(id)sender { //A button that initiates composition
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"My Mail Subject"];
    if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error;
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        NSLog(@"It's away!");
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I think you have to use an `MSMailComposeViewController` (as I have in the above example) to do what you want.

Comment: I did as same you did. It opens with some data.

Comment: What opens? Mail.app?? It doesn't in my simulator

Comment: See i do not understand Every one uses MFMailComposer App for email composing and I used the same.May be some other section of my app it's happening.As per I knew i didn't do any thing other than this.Thanks For reply

Answer (score 1):

> ... the email button should enable users to compose emails in the app ...

They mean that your program should allow people to compose emails, instead of opening Mail.app.

Comment: but even that is opening the Composer sheet ? where user can compose his own content but right now an html page is dispaling in that body.Could you please give me any link or explain a little lore by compose email.